# `connect_until_stable' error when trying to use selenium on Heroku RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run a file on Heroku that has selenium. However, I get the following error.

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service_manager.rb:130:in `connect_until_stable': unable to connect to /app/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/109.0.5414.74/chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service_manager.rb:57:in `block in start'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:41:in `locked'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service_manager.rb:54:in `start'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:83:in `launch'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:341:in `service_url'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:321:in `create_bridge'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:74:in `initialize'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `new'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:47:in `for'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.1.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-4.7.1/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:88:in `for'
        from bin/flights_data.rb:22:in `scraper'
        from bin/flights_data.rb:36:in `<main>'
```

I can't tell what the error means. I installed both the chromedriver buildpack and the the chrome buildpack. I have selenium listed in the gem file.

**gem file**

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

**test ruby file**

````
selenium

def selenium
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
    puts "HELLO"
    open_google(driver)
end

def open_google(driver)
    driver.get 'https://www.google.com/flights'
end
```

Can someone help explain the error?
````

Comment: Try out the solutions provided in this answer thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609642/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-correctly-on-heroku-with-a-rails-app

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the chrome driver add on Heroku and run restart server.