# Selenium with Headless Google Chrome on Heroku Dyno Always Times Out

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, heroku

This is similar, but not a duplicate of: [How to run Selenium Webdriver correctly on Heroku with a Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609642/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-correctly-on-heroku-with-a-rails-app)

I've tried all of the answers that are in that question, but they don't work. My output is always:

```
timed out after 60 seconds (no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z"} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeoutError)
  (Session info: headless chrome=119.0.6045.199); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception)
    from /app/lib/scraper/scraper.rb:33:in `load!'
    from bin/scrape.rb:21:in `block in <main>'
    from bin/scrape.rb:16:in `each'
    from bin/scrape.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

Here's how I'm constructing the webdriver:

```
@selenium_options = setup_selenium_opts
if chrome_bin = ENV["GOOGLE_CHROME_REAL"]
  Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = chrome_bin
end
if chrome_driver = ENV["CHROME_DRIVER_REAL"]
  Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.driver_path = chrome_driver
end
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: @selenium_options)

def setup_selenium_opts
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Bypass OS security model
  options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1480')

  return options
end
```

The ENV variables are set correctly as confirmed by running `heroku run irb` and then inspecting the `ENV` hash.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Python when running headless Chrome (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73840130/7058266), you need to use Chrome's newer headless mode if you want things to work as they do when using non-headless Chrome. The Ruby line you want for options is:

```rb
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
```

If it works in non-headless mode, then it should work in the newer headless mode too.

Comment: This didn't work on heroku. Functionality still works when I run the scraper locally. I think it's got to be something with the way I've setup my heroku dyno.

Comment: It's not worthy that the error is a timeout error - I wonder if it's something to do with the way the css is rendered to the scraper on the heroku dyno vs. on my machine

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was running locally because I was already authenticated on the site I was attempting to scrape.

Once I authenticated on Heroku, the script ran successfully.